# Iterate through filesystem from Jenkinsfile using Groovy

Tags: loops, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to iterate through the whole directory structure of a git repository from a Jenkins pipeline using groovy. But somehow my loop always stops after the first iteration.

My pipeline sets up multiple parallel stages automatically. Each of these stages should loop through their part of the filesystem (each stage clones a git repo and should loop through the files)

```
// retrieve projects list in an earlier stage

def branchedStages = [:]
    projects.each { val ->

        // set some vars

        branchedStages["${project}"] = {
            stage("build::${project}") {

                // some stuff that is working just fine

                dir("${reposDir}/${projectTitle}/${projectName}") {
                    sh "pwd"
                    sh "ls -alF"

                    echo "[INFO] Iterate project"
                    def dir = new File("${reposDir}/${projectTitle}/${projectName}")
                    dir.traverse(type: ANY) {f ->
                        println f.name
                        println f.absolutePath

                        if(f.name.endsWith('.sh')) {
                            println "..."
                            // todo: do the stuff I actually wanna do
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        parallel branchedStages
    }
}
```

This is the snippet from my pipelins script. The `ls -alF` confirms, that there are more than only one file inside the directory. Still the groovy code only shows one entry and stops afterwards.

The var `final String reposDir="/tmp/repos"` is set to an absolute path so there is no problem with being at the wrong position inside my directory tree.

This is the output from my pipeline (I removed some of the steps that are working correctly for better reading).

[image]

I don't know why my groovy snippet stops after the first file. My Groovy Version is 2.4.12.

Comment: stops without any error message? i bet there is a NonCPS issue with your snippet. why not to use native step to list files in jenkins: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace

Comment: I tried `def files = findFiles(glob: '**/*.sh')` and try to loop through the result using `files.each { f -> ` ( the loop body is the same as in my snippet above). But I got `No such DSL method 'findFiles' found among steps [archive, bat, ...` and my pipeline failed. Plus my folders which I wanna loop through are not in the workspace but in /tmp dir. Bit I guess I will change that anyway because these files belong to a job and should reside in the workspace.

Comment: One more information: My pipeline sets up multiple parallel stages automatically. Each of these stages should loop through their part of the filesystem (each stage clones a git repo and should loop through the files) ... I added these info to my question above as well.

Comment: I just changed the repository location to `/var/jenkins_home/jobs/TEMP-generate-bash-api-docs/workspace/tmp/repos` but still get the same `No such DSL method 'findFiles'` error.

Comment: Check the version of plugin, update it... https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-utility-steps/ btw, you can use your groovy code but put it into function and add annotation @NonCPS to it

Comment: Thanks man .. I did not know I had to install a plugin. With pipeline-utility-steps installed, `findFiles(glob: '**/*.sh')` works exactly as I hoped.